# transform 3 categorical variables into 1 dummy with mutate and ifelse functions

Tags: r, categorical-data, dplyr, dummy-variable

I have data from a social survey. One of the categorical variables is education. It breaks down the population into 6 groups: "1" for those who have primary education, "2" for those who have O level, "3" for those who have complee secondary education. 4 for bachelors' degree. 5 for master's, 6 for PhD.

```
   wage age sex edu area satisf
1    NA  76   2   6    1   <NA>
2 17000  26   2   6    1      1
3    NA  74   1   6    1   <NA>
4    NA  73   2   6    1   <NA>
5    NA  49   2   5    1      1
6 25000  31   1   6    1      2
```

I have previously run a regression and decided that I don't need categories 1-3. SO I would like to have the following structure:

```
DUMMY1(edu)={█(1,&edu="1" ,2,3@0,&edu=else)┤

DUMMY2(edu)={█(1,&edu="4" @0,&edu=else)┤

DUMMY3(edu)={█(1,&edu="5" @0,&edu=else)┤

DUMMY4(edu)={█(1,&edu="6" @0,&edu=else)┤
```

I need to learn how to use mutate and ifelse functions. My current command is the following:

```
vova5 <- mutate(vova4,bedu=ifelse(vova4$edu<=3,vova4$edu2 <- 1,
                                   vova4$edu2 <- vova4$edu-2))
```

but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Without your data, I would try `case_when`, something like:

Data sample:

```
vova4 <- data.frame(
  edu = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), 
  age = c(70, 56, 66, 67, 34, 55, 33, 44, 32))
```

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
vova5 <- vova4 %>% 
  mutate(Bedu = case_when(edu<=3 ~ 1, 
         edu==4 ~ 2, 
         edu==5 ~ 3, 
         TRUE ~ 4)) 

vova5
```

Or:

```
vova5 <- vova4 %>% 
  mutate(Bedu = case_when(edu<=3 ~ 1, 
         edu==4 ~ 2, 
         edu==5 ~ 3, 
         edu==6 ~ 4))
```

You will get:

```
> vova5
  edu age Bedu
1   1  70    1
2   2  56    1
3   3  66    1
4   4  67    2
5   4  34    2
6   5  55    3
7   5  33    3
8   6  44    4
9   6  32    4
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Still get error warning:                                                              
 > vova5 <- vova4%>% 
+   mutate(Bedu =  case_when(
+       edu<=3 ~ 1, 
+       edu==4 ~ 2
+       edu==5 ~ 3
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"      edu==4 ~ 2
      edu"
>       TURE ~ 4))
Error: unexpected ')' in "      TURE ~ 4)"

Comment: Try replace `TURE ~ 4` with `TRUE ~ 4`. I have also revised my answer with some data.